# Refresh parent window from child window using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening new pop-up page in new window. Now When I am pressing a html input button from child window, I want to close this child window then I want to refresh the parent window.
How I can do using javascript?

Can you anyone suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try something like this:

```
function closeAndRefresh(){
  opener.location.reload(); // or opener.location.href = opener.location.href;
  window.close(); // or self.close();
}
```

Comment: you're welcome. i've done the same mistake once, when i started learning und using javascript ;)

Comment: thanks a lot @oezi Huhhhh by mistakes we learnt something new in every day mistakes..

Answer (score 4):

you could try this in you child window:

```
function refreshParent() {
  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

  if (window.opener.progressWindow)

 {
    window.opener.progressWindow.close()
  }
  window.close();
}
```

Comment: :DD hahahha how about a tick ahaha so funny

Answer (score 3):

I tried code

```
window.close();
if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
      window.opener.location.reload();
 }
```

Its working..

Comment: you should delete this post and add the information to your initial question by editing that. answers are for answering to a question, not for giving additional information.

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.reload();` reloads the parent window.

Comment: I think it closes the child window though... perhaps you could post a more complete answer and explain how it works to the OP?

Comment: @ochi indeed it does close the child window, which is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: This approach would be useful if you need to bypass the cache: "By default, the reload() method reloads the page from the cache, but you can force it to reload the page from the server by setting the forceGet parameter to true: location.reload(true)."  [Ref. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp ].

Answer (score 0):

```
document.opener.document.location.href = document.opener.document.location.href
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this simple code:

```
// parentPage.php is the parent page you want to redirect and refresh.
window.opener.location.href="parentPage.php";
self.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This function worked for me:

```js
function closeAndRefresh(){
  opener.location.href = opener.location.href;
  window.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right expression to reload the parent window with a button within an iframe:

```js
parent.location.reload();
```