# Cross Domain Tracking with Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

I have a series of applications for an e-commerce service that I'd like to track visitors with; the user enters a site of static pages and then is directed to an application where they place their order, and then directed once more to our payment gateway. Now, Google Analytics has good documentation on how to do this, but our users authenticate through Facebook Connect. This point of authentication causes the tracking to cut off since GA sees this as the user leaving the site.

I'm wondering if there is a way to track the user through this connection, to track their flow from entering the site, all the way to the payment page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider running the FB authentication in a pop up window and once it's complete call a JS on the parent window. I think GA should hold the session.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667714/refresh-parent-window-from-child-window-using-javascript) has an example of refreshing the parent window, your solution should be similar.