# Pop up and pop in like gmail chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do popup like gmail chat popup window as well as I want to do pop-in like the way gmail does.

once the pop-out is done particular div should be open in new window and once the pop-in done the particular div should be placed in the position where it was been already, so far I am able to do the pop up the window in new window with the following code, but I don't have the idea how to do pop-in

Please note: once the pop-out done particular div should be open in another window and the variables in the main window also should be accessible in the pop-out window.

work out in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirumalaimurugan/Nyyby/) 
    
     
      
      Pop out demo

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    //<![CDATA[ 
    $(function(){
    $('.popup').click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow",              
     "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
    });
   });//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://google.com" class="popup">google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I have found the option how to open the div in new window the code as follows, now I am able to pop out the window with contents in the div, now I need to know how can I access the variable value in the pop out window and how to attach back the pop out window into that original place

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirumalaimurugan/Nyyby/2/)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>
      Popup demo
    </title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="popup">
      google
    </a>
    <div id="toNewWindow">
      Testing
      <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="click">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[ 

      $('.popup').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var w = window.open("","myWin","height=400px,width=600px");
        w.document.write( $("#toNewWindow").html() );

        $('#toNewWindow').detach();
      });

      var a=3;
      function test()
      {
        alert(a);
      }
      //]]>      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Second edit**

Now I have found the way to access the variables in between opener and child, code as follows

Now my problem is

if I have typed in the text box in child.html which is inside the iframe is not showing when on the popout.

**Opener**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Popup checking</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var winObj;
function openwindow()
{
    winObj=window.open("","_blank","height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
    var s=document.getElementById('page').innerHTML;
    console.log(s);
    //var s=document.getElementById('page');
winObj.document.write(s);
    //win.parent.detach(win);

}
function changeValue()
{
    console.log(winObj.document.getElementById('changer').value);
    winObj.document.getElementById('changer').value='changer';
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="page">
        <iframe src="child.html" width="100" height="100"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div id="page1">
    <input type="text" id="text1"/>
    <input type="button" value="popup" onclick="openwindow()"/>
    <input type="button" value="changevalue" onclick="changeValue()"/>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Child**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openerChange()
    {
            window.opener.document.getElementById('text1').value="Value changed.."
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" value="" id="changer" />
    <input type="button" value="changed" onclick="openerChange()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @rps Thanks for your reply, Yes I am expecting that only, I feel I explained that in my question and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking, but do you want to do a popup out in a new window? if you need any pop-out-pop-in functionality you can always do some custom coding in html and javascript, right?

Comment: @Shahe no problem, but in my case all the content like chart, sale analysis all will be in single window(html page) some time we will need that content to be pop-out and we will take that and show it on another monitor(4 display), if your couldn't understand what I am saying please revert me, because i'm in hurry I would have missed to explain properly.

Comment: the question is quite old already, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667714/refresh-parent-window-from-child-window-using-javascript

Comment: Maybe you need to write a Chrome Extension instead? I don't understand how you will be able to get the new window to reattach

Comment: @EliseChant that the problem for me to

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Named Window on the page your window expands from called eg. "HomeWindow".
Then expand window using similar to what you have, except rather using _blank give it a specific name like "ExpandedWindow" 
eg.

```
window.open("http://YourLink.TLD","ExpandedWindow","height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
```

then in the pop up to Retract window use these in a click function.

```
    window.open(document.URL,"HomeWindow");

    ExpandedWindow.close();
```

Comment: can you give small prototype? so that it will be useful for every one.

Comment: Ok,  here is a very basic working example: http://dialoz.com/downloads/PopUp-PopIn.zip

Comment: it doesn't fit to my question, ie: if I type mail-id and did popout I am not getting any value in mail-id text box, please go through my question where I given the source please go through that also.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want state preserved when you popout the window. It looks like you are populating the popout HTML from the `#page` node, which contains an iFrame.

First of all, know that when using an iFrame, any reparenting of the iframe node will cause a reload, losing all state. It's unfortunate ;(

If I were you, I would make it so that all event handling and state management is done in the main window. You're somewhat on the right track. When you open up the popout, if the main window is holding the state you can write that state to the opened window's iframe. Likewise when you close the popout and the iframe mounts back in the main window, you can initialize it with the correct values because the main window is keeping track of the state.

The details of how to do so...I'll leave as an exercise to the reader.